# Getting a majority of incorrect hue values using Python?

Tags: python

I wrote a code to find hue values of pixels for a huge set of images. I tested my code on 50 images before the entire set and I get about 40% of 0's for 272 293 582 pixels (exactly 110 064 805 pixels have the hue value '0').

My images definitely don't have so much red in them, so where could the problem be coming from? Here's how you can replicate it:

```
from PIL import Image
import _imaging
import colorsys
import math
import os

numberofPix = 0
zeroCount = 0

for file in os.listdir("/path/"):
    print str(file)
    im = Image.open(file)
    width, height = im.size
    rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')

    widthRange = range(width)
    heightRange = range(height)

    for i in widthRange:
        for j in heightRange:
            r, g, b = rgb_im.getpixel((i, j))
            h, s, v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r/255.0, g/255.0, b/255.0)
            h = h * 360
            h = int(round(h))
            numberofPix = numberofPix +1
            if h == 0:
                zeroCount = zeroCount +1

print str(numberofPix)
print str(zeroCount)
```

Comment: is this by any chance a file with transparency?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check but it's possible some files have transparency. Would converting them to another format fix it?

Comment: well the thing is that typically, transparency is a mask that is applied on top of the RGB image. telling your machine to ignroe or partially ignore the contents of a pixel.. So you could in fact have a very red image, that is rendered as completely transparent. But when you do rgb to hsv, get only red pixels.. also remember that  Hue is not really a numer for pure gray tones as r, g, and b have exact same values.. often a converter ends up setting hue to 0 in those cases.. see here: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm

Comment: The images I'm analyzing are screenshots from the App Store. They're not completely transparent?

Comment: nope, are they gray, black, or white?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I've just run an analysis for a screenshot that was in black & white, I get 720 630 out of 727 040 pixels that have a "hue" value of 0. How should I go about getting these colours/ignoring black and white then?

Comment: well.. as I just said, hue is .. irrelevant for all pixels with equal RGB colors. (all pure gray tones..), and without a datatype that supports NaN we have to assign some value, like 0 or 255...  since it's python, you could check for r==g and r==b, and then set h = None ;)